# Discord py How can I detect a specific Members Status

Tags: python, discord.py

How to detect a single Person in the Server.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    discord.guild.Member = 734904868334075985
    if discord.Member.status is not discord.Status.offline:
        user = client.get_user(734904868334075985)
        await user.send("Warning")`
```

I am getting the Warning and it detects... but not the specific person.

Comment: Do you want all the online users, or all the user names? Please say exactly what do you want to do

Comment: i want to detect a specific id, but i made an mistake writing this Problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) it is activated when the following changes

- status
- activity
- nickname
- roles

`before` and `after` are member objects which can be used to send message to.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if after.id == 734904868334075985:
        if after.status is not discord.Status.offline:
            # Not offline
            await after.send('Warning')
```

I hope this is what you wanted